# Update None values in django Database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm, django-viewsets

I have field in django model city which stored None but i want to update it how can i update the field data with respect to user id
I tried

```
 a=Model.objects.filter(id=1).update(City = 'Vatican')
```

this returned 1

Comment: syntax seems correct except Model you have to use actual model name.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC Its returning 1 in output it stores 1 inside a when i tried a.save() it throws error

Comment: can you please post your model also?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once): The `update()` method is applied instantly and returns the number of rows matched by the query (which may not be equal to the number of rows updated if some rows already have the new value). So the 1 here is the number of rows that got updated

Comment: what is your django version? and is'nt the value '1' your overridden ```__str__``` function? please provide your model class you just used, and a better sample i.e. actual model instead of ```Model``` that could be the parent class of your model implementation.